# Displaying MoM in highcharts for uneven months

Tags: json, highcharts

I need to benchmark this month to previous month. I run into trouble, because month durations are uneven. For each day this month, I want to display the value of the same day last month (01.Jan = 01.Feb) and vice versa (31.Jan = end of month aka 29.Feb)

For example:
For 2020 January I want to display 31 days

Fom 2020 February I want to display 29 days, but keep the line stationary even if these kinds of dates for February don't exist.

So the tooltip would be something like that:

- 29.02.2020 =  Last month value(29.01), this month value(29.02)
- 30.02.2020 = should be displayed as "30th value" or smth like that; Last month value(30.01), this month value (29.02)
- 31.02.2020 = should be displayed as "31th value" or smth like that; Last month value(31.01), this month value (29.02)

var test_data_last_month = [[Date.UTC(2020,0,1),0],[Date.UTC(2020,0,2),155752],[Date.UTC(2020,0,3),245224],[Date.UTC(2020,0,4),313143],[Date.UTC(2020,0,5),454540],[Date.UTC(2020,0,6),715791],[Date.UTC(2020,0,7),715791],[Date.UTC(2020,0,8),715791],[Date.UTC(2020,0,9),988655],[Date.UTC(2020,0,10),1026435],[Date.UTC(2020,0,11),1332754],[Date.UTC(2020,0,12),1567388],[Date.UTC(2020,0,13),1940597],[Date.UTC(2020,0,14),1940597],[Date.UTC(2020,0,15),1940597],[Date.UTC(2020,0,16),2081828],[Date.UTC(2020,0,17),2213635],[Date.UTC(2020,0,18),2255751],[Date.UTC(2020,0,19),2395119],[Date.UTC(2020,0,20),2876209],[Date.UTC(2020,0,21),2876209],[Date.UTC(2020,0,22),2876209],[Date.UTC(2020,0,23),2988469],[Date.UTC(2020,0,24),3201548],[Date.UTC(2020,0,25),3260514],[Date.UTC(2020,0,26),3581301],[Date.UTC(2020,0,27),3817162],[Date.UTC(2020,0,28),3817162],[Date.UTC(2020,0,29),3817162],**[Date.UTC(2020,0,30),4195778],[Date.UTC(2020,0,31),4593995]]**

var test_data_this_month = [[Date.UTC(2020,1,1),76095],[Date.UTC(2020,1,2),83687],[Date.UTC(2020,1,3),320969],[Date.UTC(2020,1,4),320969],[Date.UTC(2020,1,5),320969],[Date.UTC(2020,1,6),501655],[Date.UTC(2020,1,7),631921],[Date.UTC(2020,1,8),691171],[Date.UTC(2020,1,9),805063],[Date.UTC(2020,1,10),805063],[Date.UTC(2020,1,11),805063],[Date.UTC(2020,1,12),805063],[Date.UTC(2020,1,13),1043119],[Date.UTC(2020,1,14),1311065],[Date.UTC(2020,1,15),1400422],[Date.UTC(2020,1,16),1778001],[Date.UTC(2020,1,17),2084701],[Date.UTC(2020,1,18),2084701],[Date.UTC(2020,1,19),2084701],[Date.UTC(2020,1,20),2139867],[Date.UTC(2020,1,21),2501355],[Date.UTC(2020,1,22),2546408],[Date.UTC(2020,1,23),0],[Date.UTC(2020,1,24),0],[Date.UTC(2020,1,25),0],[Date.UTC(2020,1,26),0],[Date.UTC(2020,1,27),0],**[Date.UTC(2020,1,28),0],[Date.UTC(2020,1,29),0]]**

[two months separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi2gz.png)
[two months in the same graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f5cs.png)

I've been driving myself crazy over this issue. Any help is much appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `x` as successive values increasing by 1 (default behavior) and store date as a custom property. To show the values in a tooltip in the way you want, use `tooltip.formatter` function:

```
tooltip: {
  shared: true,
  formatter: function() {
    var points = this.points,
      series = points[0].series.chart.series,
      point,
      i = 0,
      str = '';

    for (; i < series.length; i++) {
      if (points[i]) {
        point = points[i].point;

      } else {
        point = series[i].points[series[i].points.length - 1];
      }

      str += '<span style="color:' + point.color + '">●</span> ' +
        point.series.name + ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', point.customDate) +
        ': <b>' + point.y + '</b><br/>'
    }

    return str;
  }
},
xAxis: {
  tickPositions: [1, 11, 21, 31]
},
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    keys: ['customDate', 'y'],
    pointStart: 1
  }
},
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4986/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointStart

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.keys